# EF Core Database First Approach: Scaffold-DbContext is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core and I am trying to generate the Model from the Database. I have created a separate ASP.NET Core Web Application, because generating that from a class library didn't work for me.

I have  generated the entity classes from the database successfully several times, but suddenly it stopped working. This is really weird because I this is not the first time, and I am not change anything, what's causing it to stop working?

**This is project.json:**

```
  {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {

    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}
```

**This is the command:**

```
 Scaffold-DbContext "Server= myserver;Database=db;User Id=sa;Password=pass;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir EntityModels
```

**The Error:**

```
 Scaffold-DbContext : The term 'Scaffold-DbContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver;Database=db...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Scaffold-DbContext:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I restarted visual studio and the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

The version in `dependencies` is different than `tools`:

From `dependencies`:

`"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",`

And from `tools`:

`"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",`

Comment: I am 100% sure that it was working with those packages. I tried to change it as you mentioned and it gave another error: `System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Attempt by method 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Configuration.Internal.ModelConfiguration.get_EntityConfigurations()' to access method 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityTypeNameComparer..ctor()' failed.) ---> System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Configuration.Internal.ModelConfiguration.get_EntityConfigurations()`

Comment: See the EF 1.1 release notes [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/) and scroll down to "Upgrading tooling packages" - you'll probably need to use the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` tooling.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. However, the same project is still working on another machine.